# Why is JSON object not returning a key set?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code, first I get the object and parse it as a json object.

```
var PJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Later on, I run a simple for each to get keys and values from that object:

```
//get keyset from JSON object 

    for (var key in PJson.user) {

        console.log('here');
                     console.log(key);

}
```

Finally, here is my output:

```
[INFO] :   here

[INFO] :   0
```

keys are =0

The JSON object looks like this:

```
Get Request is called

[INFO] :   (

[INFO] :           {

[INFO] :           "auth_token" = xxxxxxx;

[INFO] :           name = "John dot";

[INFO] :           nickname = tg;

[INFO] :           pictures =         (

[INFO] :               "http://xxxx.com/me/picture"

[INFO] :           );

[INFO] :           yob = 1986;

[INFO] :       }

[INFO] :   )
```

Thanks.

**Edit** - original json object from the api:

```
200 (OK)
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "status": "OK", 
    "user": [{
        "auth_token": "xxxxxx", 
        "name": "John Dot", 
        "pictures":["http://xxxxx.com/me/picture"],
        "nickname":"tg",
        "yob": "1986",

    }]
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

I have managed to turn the array into a json object through my code:

```
var PJson = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
PJson = JSON.parse(PJson);
```

I get the following back:

```
   {
        "status": "OK", 
        "user": [{
            "auth_token": "xxxxxx", 
            "name": "John Dot", 
            "pictures":["http://xxxxx.com/me/picture"],
            "nickname":"tg",
            "yob": "1986",

        }]
    }
```

It is valid JSON now.

The trouble is , when I run the for each loop

```
for (var key in PJson) {

        console.log('here');
                     console.log(key);

}
```

I get garbage back, any idea why? just a series of keys 1,2,3,4,5,6[...],138

Comment: Wheres the `user` object you try and tierate over?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(this.responseText)` and put it here?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. The brackets `()` shouldn't be there and the key names need to be enclosed in quotes `"`. And you should have `:` rather than `=`. See http://www.json.org/

Comment: try `for (var key in PJson.user[0])`

Comment: updated my question with the original json from the api

Comment: `PJson.user` is an array of objects.

Comment: Not sure why it is returning an array of object when I explicitly defined a JSON object in the API

Comment: Amended original question.

Answer (score 1):

`PJson.user` is an array with 1 item.

When you do `for (var key in PJson.user)` **key** is just the index of the array **0**

So in that case `for (var key in PJson.user[0])` should give you all the keys of **user**

Comment: I need it to return a JSON object not an array, do I need to parse it again? Not sure why it is returning an array when I defined a JSON object in the api.

Comment: What is producing the json?

Comment: rest is used to make an api call to a server - response is a json object (this.responseText);

Comment: The server is sending back the response wrong if it should not be an array.  If you don't control the server code then you can not change it.  But you can just handle it as an array and process the first element if this is how the response is as designed.

Comment: Managed to solve this , see my edit in the original question. However, I am unable to itterate through the JSON object with a simple foreach loop. I dont get the keys back only numbers.

Comment: try `console.log(PJson.length)` **138**, `this.responseText` is probably already a string.  So you are just double escaping it calling `JSON.stringify(this.responseText)`.  `for (var key in "abcde")` == 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: That is exactly what's happening - I checked with typeof, it returned a string. The trouble is I can't convert it into a JSON object

Comment: Thanks, I still dont understand why my response object is not a json object. Looks like you have had to fiddle around with arrays.